# how much does the radius of a circle need to increase to give x more dots in the circle?

Tags: circles

[the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6qDN.png)

so i understand that there would be 13 dots within this circle
and it needs 8 more (21 in total) points. The points that needed would be $(+/- 1, +/- 2), (+/- 2, +/- 1)$. but how do you work out the increase in radius needed?

also the answer is radius increase of $\sqrt 5 - 2$

Comment: How far from the origin are your four added points?

Comment: You are not attracting much interest because people do not like to click trough to find the question.  Please type it up so your question is self contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if im suposed to delete the question or add the answer and leave it, but i found the answer.

As the minimum expansion would be at (+/−1,+/−2),(+/−2,+/−1), we can use Pythagoras's theorem to find the new radius.

eg/

> 2²+1²= r²

so the radius of the new circle would be √5

the increase in radius is therefore √5 - 2, which is the answer